# How to declare a property as a function in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa

class VC1: NSViewController {
    let aFunctionVar ()->Void
}
```

The compiler however tells me: "Class VC1 has no initializers"

According to the swift example in Apple Swift iBook, they did their examplle like so:

```
var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts
```

But in my case, I'm trying to create a property variable. It is not yet known what the variable will be, so i can't set it there. Any help?

**Edit** - I already know how to make variables optional and lazy when it comes to simple String/Array/Dictionary types etc. But this is a function type property variable. It is meant to hold a function of type `()->Void`.  Any help on how this can be done?

In objectiveC this can be done by making a block property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)  void (^aFunctionVar)();
```

Comment: Make it an optional var.

Comment: how do i make it an optional var? adding a `?` at the end gives me the same error

Comment: Did you try `( ( )->Void )?` ?

Comment: Did you also use the "var" keyword in addition to "?" ?

Comment: -____- thanks guys..  I thought adding a question mark (without the brackets) made it optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `projectLaunchData` as an optional `var`:

```
import Cocoa

class VC1: NSViewController {
    var projectLaunchData: (()->Void)?
}
```

Then you can assign a value later:

```
func test() {
    print("this works")
}

let myVC = VC1()

// assign the function
myVC.projectLaunchData = test

// Call the function using optional chaining.  This will safely do nothing
// if projectLaunchData is nil, and call the function if it has been assigned.
// If the function returns a value, it will then be optional because it was
// called with the optional chaining syntax.
myVC.projectLaunchData?()
```

Comment: thanks much.. i didnt realize i had to have enclose it in ( <-brackets-> )

Comment: You're welcome.  You need to enclose it in parentheses so that Swift knows that the entire function is optional and not just the return value.

Answer (score 1):

If the value will be known after the object is setup, you can use a lazy variable:

```
class LazyTester {
    lazy var someLazyString: String = {
       return "So sleepy"
    }()
}
var myLazyTester = LazyTester()
myLazyTester.someLazyString
```

The compiler is giving you that error because you are defining a mandatory stored variable, `projectLaunchData`, but not giving it a value.  If you know the variables value at init time, you can set it at init time.

Comment: making something lazy var works, with normal variables. This i know how to do. But this is not a simple String type variable. It is function type variable. How do i make the variable above to be lazy?